# java calendar returns wrong hour_of_day

Tags: java.util.calendar

I have the following code:

```
Calendar cal= Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1994);   
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 03);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
```

After running it I expect:

```
cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
```

to return **0**, but it returns **1**.

If I use a different year/month, it works fine.
Also, setting another hour works fine, it happens only for 0.

Is there something special about April 1994? What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Gives 0 as expected to me: http://ideone.com/85WUH0

Comment: weird... maybe a TimeZone issue? Thanks for checking

Answer (score 1):

I was using Israel TZ and due to DST transition the hour 0 on April 1st '94 does not exist.